# Temperature Conversion not working, all results 1 "slot" off being correct

Tags: java, math, data-conversion

```
public class TempTabl {
    
  public static void main (String[] args) {
      double a = 0;
      double b = 0;
      double c = 0;
      double z = 0;
      System.out.printf("  Temperature    |       Temperature%n");
      System.out.printf("    (degrees)    |        (degrees) %n");
      System.out.printf(" F           C   |      C           F%n");

      z = 0;
      while (a <= 450) {
          b = fahrenheit(a,b);
          a = -40 + (5 * z);
          System.out.printf(" %-10s  %4f| %-10s  %4f", a, b, a, c);
          System.out.println("");

          z++;
     }
  }

  public static double fahrenheit(double a,double b) {
     b = ((a-32)*5)/9;
     return b;
  }

  public static double celsius(double z,double c) {
     c = -40 + ( 9 * z);
     return c;
  }
}
```

what i got:

```
        Temperature    |      
         (degrees)     |        
   F               C   |     
 -40.0       -17.777778| 
 -35.0       -40.000000| 
 -30.0       -37.222222|
```

what i expected to get:

```
       Temperature      |       
        (degrees)       |   
      F           C     |    
   −40.000     −40.000  |  
   −35.000     −37.222  | 
   −30.000     −34.444  |
```

Comment: setting initial A value to -40 makes it so its still 1 placeholder off but in the opposite direction, starts with two -40's then correct numbers

Comment: calculate `a` **before** using it in `fahrenheit(a, b)` || and using a `for` loop instead of a `while`, would be easier to write/read: `for (double a = -40; a <= 450; a += 5)` or similar

Answer (score 0):

The solution is: inside the while loop when you are calling the fahrenheit the parameter 'a' is zero so you should define 'a' before calling the fahreheit function that will fix it and you will get the output as you expected

```java
while (a <= 450) {
    a = -40 + (5 * z);
    b = fahrenheit(a, b);
    System.out.printf(" %-10s  %4f| %-10s  %4f", a, b, a, c);
    System.out.println("");

    z++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> *'Temperature Conversion not working, all results 1 "slot" off being correct ...'*

I'm not sure if you are referring to the formatting, or part of the math.

If you are referring to the math, the *celsius* equation is incorrect.
*[Wikipedia – Conversion of scales of temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_of_scales_of_temperature)*.

Here is the correct equation,

```java
public static double celsius(double z) {
    return (z * 9 / 5) + 32;
}
```

For the formatting, it looks like you'll need to use the *width* and *precision* format-specifiers.

There is a full list of format-specifiers on the *Formatter* *JavaDoc* page.
*[Formatter (Java SE 20 & JDK 20)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html)*

To match the expected output, I had to adjust your header fields.

```java
System.out.printf("       Temperature      |       Temperature%n");
System.out.printf("        (degrees)       |        (degrees) %n");
System.out.printf("      F           C     |      C           F%n");
```

And then, I used *%10.3f*, which will use *10* total characters, and 3 decimal values.

Additionally, you're going to want to evaluate *a* first, within the *loop*.
And, I removed the unnecessary *b* parameter from the *fahrenheit* method.

```java
while (a <= 450) {
    a = -40 + (5 * z);
    b = fahrenheit(a);
    System.out.printf("%10.3f  %10.3f  |", a, b);
    c = celsius(b);
    System.out.printf("%10.3f  %10.3f%n", b, c);
    z++;
}
```

Here is the full re-factor.

```java
public static void main (String[] args) {
    double a = 0;
    double b = 0;
    double c = 0;
    double z = 0;
    System.out.printf("       Temperature      |       Temperature%n");
    System.out.printf("        (degrees)       |        (degrees) %n");
    System.out.printf("      F           C     |      C           F%n");

    z = 0;
    while (a <= 450) {
        a = -40 + (5 * z);
        b = fahrenheit(a);
        System.out.printf("%10.3f  %10.3f  |", a, b);
        c = celsius(b);
        System.out.printf("%10.3f  %10.3f%n", b, c);
        z++;
    }
}

public static double fahrenheit(double a) {
    return ((a-32)*5)/9;
}

public static double celsius(double z) {
    return (z * 9 / 5) + 32;
}
```

Output

```
       Temperature      |       Temperature
        (degrees)       |        (degrees) 
      F           C     |      C           F
   -40.000     -40.000  |   -40.000     -40.000
   -35.000     -37.222  |   -37.222     -35.000
   -30.000     -34.444  |   -34.444     -30.000
   -25.000     -31.667  |   -31.667     -25.000
...
   440.000     226.667  |   226.667     440.000
   445.000     229.444  |   229.444     445.000
   450.000     232.222  |   232.222     450.000
   455.000     235.000  |   235.000     455.000
```

Comment: the quality of your answer will make me try 10 times longer before asking anything else; i feel i stole that effort from someone else but thank you so much.